# Django Inlineでのプルダウンや入力欄の表示制御

Tags: django

Djangoで質問です
以下２つのモデルがあり、PriceのdataidはPriceDataのidと紐づいています

```
class Price(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID")
    dataid = models.ForeignKey("PriceData",on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="詳細データID",)
    
class PriceData(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID")
```

admin.pyで以下のようにPriceのInlineを作成しています。

```
class PriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Price
    fields = ["id","name"]

    formfield_overrides = {
        django_models.TextField: {
            "widget": forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": 3, "cols": 20})
        },

    }

    show_change_link = False
    can_delete = False
```

上記Inlineをadmin.pyで以下のように読み込ませています

```
class PriceDataModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PriceInline]
```

PriceInlineでPriceDataに紐づく件数分だけ「"id","name"」の入力欄を出したいのですがどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。
また、既存データのidは選択不可(disabled)にして、追加ボタンを押して追加された入力欄のみ、idを選択可能にする方法はありますでしょうか。